# Sorting array of string based on first character value

Tags: c++, string, sorting, string-comparison, function-definition

I was reading about string and function pointer in C++. There I found a problem sort array of string based on first character value.
**And here is my code solution.**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool compare1(const void *a, const void  *b)
{
    string c = *(string *)a;
    string d = *(string *)b;
    return c[0]<d[0];
}

int main()
{

    string str[3];
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" string";
        cin>>str[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"Before sort"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)                               
    {
        cout<<str[i]<<" ";
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    sort(str.begin(),str.end(),compare1);
    
    cout<<"After sort"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<str[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting compile time error: **[Error] request for member 'begin' in 'str', which is of non-class type 'std::string [3] {aka std::basic_string [3]}'**

How to fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the C library's `qsort` with the C++ library's `std::sort`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but you can use a lambda to simplify your code: `std::sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str), [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { return s1[0] < s2[0]; });`

Comment: It looks almost like you're learning programming and C++ from a so-called "competition" or "online judge" site. Don't do that, that's not what they're for. Get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) to read, and take some classes. You need to do that because you have multiple basic errors in your code.

Comment: you shouldn't use `void*`, especially when the method can only work correctly when `string*`s are passed (though you dont need pointers in the first place)

Comment: Aside from the actual answers, you should make sure that your comparison function also checks whether the strings actually have a first element, if you don't want to have a segmentation fault in wait.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What are some other basic error can u mentioned them?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But we can type-cast it to string if we are using void * .

Comment: @Hashinclude but why would you? The function could be `bool compare1(const string *a, const string  *b)`. Your function can be called with pointers to anything but has undefined behavior for most of them

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. `str` is a raw array and doesn't have member function named `begin` and `end`. You can use `std::begin` and `std::end` instead.
2. `std::sort` passes the elements for comparing; `compare1` should accept `std::string`s instead of pointers.

E.g.

```
bool compare1(const string& c, const string& d)
{
    // for empty strings
    if (c.length() == 0 || d.length() == 0)
        return c.length() < d.length();

    return c[0] < d[0];
}
```

then

```
sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str), compare1);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QPcdbZL9N6UVY8rg)

Comment: I propose that you add something that catches whether the strings are of length zero in the comparator. Wouldn't want there to be a segmentation fault in wait.

Comment: @Aziuth Nice idea.

Comment: @Hashinclude It's just how [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) works, you have to follow its rules. *The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type RandomIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them.​*

Comment: Okay thanks I got confused it with qsort() in C language where we can use const void* inside comparator and then typecast it to desired data type.

Comment: @Hashinclude C and C++ are quite different. In most cases you won't use raw pointers (and arrays) in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ arrays don't have a `begin` member.

Either use the function-style overloads:

```
sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str), compare1);
```

or use a `std::vector<std::string> str` instead.

or use `std::array<std::string, 3>`, which is a fixed size but *does* support the `begin` member.

Comment: Or since the size of the array is known at compile-time, `std::array<std::string, 3>`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `string` is the name of the standard class `std::string`.

You declared an array of three objects of the type `string`

```
string str[3];
```

Arrays are not classes. So they do not have member functions including `begin` and `end`.

Thus this statement

```
sort(str.begin(),str.end(),compare1);
```

is incorrect.

There are general functions `std::begin` and `std::end` declared in the header  that could be used for example like

```
#include <iterator>

//...

sort( std::begin( str ), std::end( str ), compare1 );
```

Or without these functions you could write

```
sort( str, str + 3, compare1 );
```

On the other hand, the function compare1 is incorrect. The function sort passes to the comparison function two objects of the type `std::string` or references to such object.

It must be declared and defined at least the following way

```
bool compare1( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    return s1[0] < s2[0];
}
```

Comment: Why we can't use void* inside compare function?

Comment: @Hashinclude Because the function sort does not passes to the comparison function pointers.

Comment: So is there any concept that we can use void* inside compare function only when we are operating on basic data type like (char, array pointer of char type)?

Comment: @Hashinclude You can use the type void * for parameters of a comparison function then it gets arguments of pointer types.